# Optimal way to apply the same join to 20 columns (with unique output variables)?

Tags: r, join

Basically, I'm joining 2 dataframes one of which (game logs) has 20 fields full of "playerID" data  and I'm joining it with another dataframe (Lahman::Appearances [w/ a key for a different playerID scheme]) which has "GS" data. So VisitorBatting1PlayerID will have a "VisitorBatting1PlayerIDGS" field as will VisitorBatting2PlayerID...

How can I just have the join/apply function go across the dataframe in one go? Is that a quicker calculation? Look at all 20 values in each row for a matching ID in "appearance" without having to brute force this one by one?

secondary question:
Retro_Temp3 `enter code here`<- Retro_Temp2 %>% mutate(Home_most_GS = apply(.[33,43:52], 1, function(x) names(x)[maxn(1)(x)]))

I'm not sure why this isn't working. When I run the actual filter, I'm only getting outputs on the Visitor side which makes no conceptual sense so it's obviously wrong.

```
Retro_Output <- tibble()
Chadwick <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chadwickbureau/baseballdatabank/master/core/People.csv")
```

`for (i in 1970:1980)
{
Appearance <- Lahman::Appearances %>% filter(yearID <= i) %>% group_by(playerID) %>% summarise(GS = sum(GS))
Appearance <- left_join(Appearance,chadwick, by = c("playerID" = "bbrefID")) %>% select(key_retro,GS) %>% rename(playerID = retroID)

```
  Retro_Temp <- read_csv(...)

  Retro_Temp <- Retro_Temp %>% select(Date:LengthInOuts,VisitorStartingPitcherID,VisitorBatting1PlayerID,VisitorBatting2PlayerID,VisitorBatting3PlayerID,VisitorBatting4PlayerID,VisitorBatting5PlayerID,VisitorBatting6PlayerID,VisitorBatting7PlayerID,VisitorBatting8PlayerID,VisitorBatting9PlayerID,HomeStartingPitcherID,HomeBatting1PlayerID,HomeBatting2PlayerID,HomeBatting3PlayerID,HomeBatting4PlayerID,HomeBatting5PlayerID,HomeBatting6PlayerID,HomeBatting7PlayerID,HomeBatting8PlayerID,HomeBatting9PlayerID)
  Retro_Temp2 <- left_join(Retro_Temp,Appearance, by = c("VisitorStartingPitcherID" = "playerID")) %>% rename(VisitorStartingPitcherIDGS = GS)
print(Retro_Temp2$VisitorStartingPitcherIDGS)
    Retro_Temp2 <- left_join(Retro_Temp2,Appearance, by = c("VisitorBatting1PlayerID" = "playerID")) %>% rename(VisitorBatting1PlayerIDGS = GS)
  Retro_Temp2 <- left_join(Retro_Temp2,Appearance, by = c("VisitorBatting2PlayerID" = "playerID")) %>% rename(VisitorBatting2PlayerIDGS = GS)
Retro_Temp2 <- left_join(Retro_Temp2,Appearance, by = c("VisitorBatting3PlayerID" = "playerID")) %>% rename(VisitorBatting3PlayerIDGS = GS)
Retro_Temp2 <- left_join(Retro_Temp2,Appearance, by = c("VisitorBatting4PlayerID" = "playerID"))%>% rename(VisitorBatting4PlayerIDGS = GS)
Retro_Temp2 <- left_join(Retro_Temp2,Appearance, by = c("VisitorBatting5PlayerID" = "playerID"))%>% rename(VisitorBatting5PlayerIDGS = GS)
Retro_Temp2 <- left_join(Retro_Temp2,Appearance, by = c("VisitorBatting6PlayerID" = "playerID"))%>% rename(VisitorBatting6PlayerIDGS = GS)
Retro_Temp2 <- left_join(Retro_Temp2,Appearance, by = c("VisitorBatting7PlayerID" = "playerID"))%>% rename(VisitorBatting7PlayerIDGS = GS)
Retro_Temp2 <- left_join(Retro_Temp2,Appearance, by = c("VisitorBatting8PlayerID" = "playerID"))%>% rename(VisitorBatting8PlayerIDGS = GS)
Retro_Temp2 <- left_join(Retro_Temp2,Appearance, by = c("VisitorBatting9PlayerID" = "playerID"))%>% rename(VisitorBatting9PlayerIDGS = GS)

Retro_Temp2 <- left_join(Retro_Temp2,Appearance, by = c("HomeStartingPitcherID" = "playerID")) %>% rename(HomeStartingPitcherGS = GS)
                     
Retro_Temp2 <- left_join(Retro_Temp2,Appearance, by = c("HomeBatting1PlayerID" = "playerID"))%>% rename(HomeBatting1PlayerIDGS = GS)
Retro_Temp2 <- left_join(Retro_Temp2,Appearance, by = c("HomeBatting2PlayerID" = "playerID"))%>% rename(HomeBatting2PlayerIDGS = GS)
Retro_Temp2 <- left_join(Retro_Temp2,Appearance, by = c("HomeBatting3PlayerID" = "playerID"))%>% rename(HomeBatting3PlayerIDGS = GS)
Retro_Temp2 <- left_join(Retro_Temp2,Appearance, by = c("HomeBatting4PlayerID" = "playerID"))%>% rename(HomeBatting4PlayerIDGS = GS)
Retro_Temp2 <- left_join(Retro_Temp2,Appearance, by = c("HomeBatting5PlayerID" = "playerID"))%>% rename(HomeBatting5PlayerIDGS = GS)
Retro_Temp2 <- left_join(Retro_Temp2,Appearance, by = c("HomeBatting6PlayerID" = "playerID"))%>% rename(HomeBatting6PlayerIDGS = GS)
Retro_Temp2 <- left_join(Retro_Temp2,Appearance, by = c("HomeBatting7PlayerID" = "playerID"))%>% rename(HomeBatting7PlayerIDGS = GS)
Retro_Temp2 <- left_join(Retro_Temp2,Appearance, by = c("HomeBatting8PlayerID" = "playerID"))%>% rename(HomeBatting8PlayerIDGS = GS)
Retro_Temp2 <- left_join(Retro_Temp2,Appearance, by = c("HomeBatting9PlayerID" = "playerID")) %>% rename(HomeBatting9PlayerIDGS = GS)


maxn <- function(n) function(x) order(x, decreasing = TRUE)[n]
#Appearances3 <- Appearances2 %>% mutate(position = apply(.[9:21], 1, function(x) names(x)[maxn(1)(x)]))
#include home/away starter with opposite team
Retro_Temp3 <- Retro_Temp2 %>% mutate(Home_most_GS = apply(.[33,43:52], 1, function(x) names(x)[maxn(1)(x)]))
Retro_Temp3 <- Retro_Temp3 %>% mutate(Vistor_most_GS = apply(.[33:43], 1, function(x) names(x)[maxn(1)(x)]))
Retro_Temp4 <- Retro_Temp3 %>% filter(Vistor_most_GS == "HomeStartingPitcherGS" | Home_most_GS == "VisitorStartingPitcherGS" )

Retro_Output <- bind_rows(Retro_Output,Retro_Temp4)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the `Retro_Temp` data that you are using so I will generate a sample dataset from my end.

In general, when you find yourself joining over the same column in one dataframe with different  columns in another, one approach is to get the data in long format and then perform the join.

```
#Data
set.seed(123)
x <- data.frame(id = 1:5, newvalue = letters[1:5])
y <- data.frame(id1 = sample(5), id2 = sample(5))

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#Currently you are doing

x %>%
  left_join(y, by = c('id' = 'id1')) %>%
  left_join(y, by = c('id' = 'id2'))


#What instead you can do is

y %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('id')) %>%
  left_join(x, by = c('value' = 'id'))
```

Comment: So what's the knockon effect for the filter?

It would be something like (holding first 9 variables of dataset constant as an ID),

value for "HomeStartingpitcher" > any specific value for  "starts_with('Visitor") | [or] [everything to the left but swapping out VisitorStartingPitcher > "columns starting with Home"]

max in columns within range defined 2 levels down (matches ID & Matches partial name).